# How Can I Paste The Copy Values Where "Test" Is

Tags: vb.net, excel

```
oExcel.Worksheets("spring").Columns("A").Copy()
oExcel.Worksheets("spring").Columns("B").Copy()

Dim LastRow As Long

LastRow = oSheet.Range("A4000").End(Excel.XlDirection.xlUp).Row + 1
oSheet.Range("A" & LastRow).Value = "Test"
oSheet.Range("B" & LastRow).Value = "Test"
```

I have tried:

```
oSheet.Range("B" & LastRow).Value = oExcel.Worksheets("spring").Columns("B").PasteSpecial()
```

and this doesn't work either

Comment: I suspect `Copy` and `PasteSpecial` are functions that perform actions rather than returning a value that can be assigned to something else. Isn't there a `.value` of the cell you can access instead or something?

Answer (score 0):

```
oSheet.Range("B" & LastRow).PasteSpecial()
```